# Drawing out reversed Strings with Graphics.drawString

Tags: java, drawstring

What I want to do is printing out Numbers as a String via Graphics.drawString.

They will be the scale for an coordinate system which looks like this:

[image: coordinate system]

As you can see its reversed, negative numbers in positive y-direction and positve in negative y-direction, which, obviously, is wrong.

To generate them I use the following  simple for-condition:

```
for (int i =  -y; i<=y; i++){
            stift.drawString(""+(i-12), canvas.getWidth()/2, i*scale+4);}
```

where y describes the total length (12 negative + 12 positive numbers = 24 in total in this case). 
I tried multiple times but couldnt figure out how to change the for condition in order to reverse the drawn Strings so they are ordered correctly.

Could you please give me an explanation and solution? 
Best Regards.

Comment: If only there was an operation that could change the sign of a number...

Comment: stift.drawString(""+(12-i), canvas.getWidth()/2, i*scale+4);